# Minimum of $f(x) = \frac{1}{a}\cos^4 \frac{\pi x}{2} + a \sin^4 \frac{\pi x}{2} +\sin\pi x (b\sin\pi x-c)$ for $x\in [0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

In my quantum-physics research, I am faced with the following single-variable trigonometric optimization problem that I would wish to solve analytically.

**Problem:** Let $a,b,c, x \in \mathbb{R}$, and assume  $a > 1$ and $c > 0$. Consider the function
$$f\left(x\right)= \frac{1}{a}\cos^4 \frac{\pi x}{2} + a \sin^4  \frac{\pi x}{2} +\sin\left(\pi x\right) \left[b\sin\left(\pi x\right)-c\right].$$
Find, in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$, the critical points and the minimum of $f$ over the closed unit interval $A=\left[0,1\right]$.

**Remarks:**
The (excluded) case $a=1$ would be fairly simple, resulting in the global minimum point(s)
$$
x_\mathrm{min} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1/2,&\textrm{if } 2b \leq 1+c, \\ \frac{2}{\pi}\arccos\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-c^2/\left(2b-1\right)^2}}, &\textrm{if }2b > 1+c. \end{array} \right. \nonumber
$$
for which
$$
f\left(x_\mathrm{min}\right) =\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1/2+b -c,&\textrm{if }2b \leq 1+c, \\ 1+c^2/\left(2-4b\right),&\textrm{if }2b > 1+c.\\ \end{array} \right. \nonumber
$$
The case under consideration appears to be more complicated. However, numerical inspection indicates that nothing particularly drastic changes between the two cases: the function only becomes "tilted" and the symmetry about $x=1/2$ gets broken. This also means that for $a>1$, the global minimum point will always be $\leq 1/2$.

The problem has arisen in the context of actual quantum-physics research, where $f$ corresponds to the energy of a two-level system, and $x$ determines the relative populations of the two states. Any help in obtaining an analytical solution, if it turns out to be feasible, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your interest and valuable time!